# Changing divs z-index using jQuery focusin and focusout

Tags: jquery, html, popup, focus, z-index

Is there any cleaner and more dynamic way than [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/efr4M/) to create div popups that change z-index as they become focused and unfocused?

HTML:

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
#div1 {
    background-color:red;
}
#div2 {
    background-color:green;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$("#div1").draggable();
$("#div2").draggable();

$("#div1").mousedown(function () {
    $("#div1").css("z-index", 2);
    $("#div2").css("z-index", 1);
});

$("#div2").mousedown(function () {
    $("#div1").css("z-index", 1);
    $("#div2").css("z-index", 2);
});
```

I tried using .blur, .focus, .focusin and .focusout methods but they didn't seem to work for me. I need a few div popups with some input fields inside. The divs will directly inside body.

Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4CpWs/) that shows how I tried using .focusin and .focusout. I also tried .blur and focus accordingly.

With focusin and focusout:

```
$("#div1").draggable();
$("#div2").draggable();

$("#div1").focusin(function () {
    $("#div1").css("z-index", 2);
});
$("#div2").focusin(function () {
    $("#div2").css("z-index", 2);
});
$("#div1").focusout(function () {
    $("#div1").css("z-index", 1);
});
$("#div2").focusout(function () {
    $("#div2").css("z-index", 1);
});
```

Thanks :)

EDIT:

Ended up using [Amit Sonis method](http://jsfiddle.net/4CpWs/2/). Much cleaner than my original :)

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve, `.mousedown` event is wroking properly, check [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/4CpWs/2/)

Comment: Imagine if I had 10 popups, each of the popup div mousedown events would have to go through every other popup div. If I could use focusin and focus out I could only change the divs z-index when the focus changes.

Comment: The fiddle you provided is pretty much acceptable answer, didn't even think of setting classes to them.. Thanks :) I would still like to know why focusin and focusout won't work.

Comment: Just on a side note, please consider making defining `$("#div1")` and `$("#div2")` as variables as you're using them more than once. This increases performance.

Answer (score 1):

Use `dragstart` and `dragstop` events in the context

```
$("#div1").draggable();
$("#div2").draggable();

$( "#div1" ).on( "dragstart", function( event, ui ) {

    $(this).css("z-index" , 2);
    $("#div2").css("z-index" , 1);
});

$( "#div2" ).on( "dragstart", function( event, ui ) {

    $(this).css("z-index" , 2);
    $("#div1").css("z-index" , 1);
});
```

Check:

Drag start: [Dragstart](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-start)

Drag stop: [Dragstop](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-stop)

You are able to access current event in both function calls.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4CpWs/5/)

Comment: Still doesn't solve my problem, I want it to work like OS windows. You click them and they stay on top until you click something else.

Comment: Ok tell what do you want actually?

Comment: Click popup, the popup becomes focused and the previously focused popup becomes unfocused. Focused popup gets z-index 2 and unfocused popups get z-index 1.

Comment: Just to be clear this has nothing to do draggable in general. I just added it to better simulate the situation I'm having.

Comment: That is the same as my first example with the exception of dragstart and "$(this)". Doesn't fix the dynamical problem.

Answer (score 1):

@Tero Heiskanen...

As per jQuery API Guidance for .Focusin and .Focusout functions, which inherits behaviour from .Focus() function, this functions are applicable to limited elements of sets like.. input, select, a etc. So probably you can not use these functions over "div" element.

However, if you want to still want to trigger these events for "div" you have to apply "tabindex" attribute to them, but they may be only accessible by keyboard TAB key navigation.

Here you have breif about above at jQuery site : http://api.jquery.com/focus/#entry-longdesc

Comment: I do remember reading that and that is why I was trying to use .focusin: "The focusin event is sent to an element when it, or any element inside of it, gains focus". I guess it only works if the div has inputfields inside. Thanks for the explanation :)